# Need to pick value from Config property - Node plus react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs

It is my first time working on the Front end. The application is Node plus react.  It has the below directories:

--config

--flow-typed

--node_modules

--script

--server

--src

There is a radio button on the app which has a default selected value now. I need to pick up the value from the system registry. The file where the default value for the radio is being set is in a package under /src.

Instead of :

```
color: Colors.RED
```

I need to do

```
color: process.env.COLOR
```

When I do above, the radio button now has no value selected by default.

If I add a constant in

```
 /config/env.js as :

const COLOR = process.env.COLOR;
console.log("-------------COLOR IS :" + COLOR);
```

It logs correctly. But it is not being picked up from under the

```
/src/myconcerneddirectory.
```

Under /scripts, there is a start.js, I have added the process.env.COLOR there for testing purposes. I start the app using npm start(for node) and npm run start-server(for react).

Comment: are you using `dotenv`? can you share your `npm start` script from your `package.json`?

Comment: No I dont think we are using dotenv because there is no .env file in my project. There  is a /config/env.js though which i mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case you use webpack, you need to specify your global variable (in your case it’s the process.env.COLOR) in your webpack config. That you can do with DefinePlugin.
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.COLOR': process.env.COLOR
});
```